# How do I compare dates when the month is set to dutch

Tags: php, strtotime, setlocale

I have to compare the date of today to a date set in dutch and I have no idea how to do that. This is what I tried already.

```
$today = date('Ymd');
$timeToday = strtotime($today);

$setlocale = setlocale(LC_ALL,'nl_NL', 'dutch');
$timeStartDate = strtotime($date['startDate']); // This date is formated dd-mm-yyyy where the month is written in dutch so 11 Mei 2020 as an example 

if($timeStartDate > $timeToday){
 //do something
}
```

I tried setting the locale but when I echo $timeStartDate it's just an empty string. How could I solve this? I can't change the date in the database since this is not my project and a lot depends on it already.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, [`strtotime()`](http://php.net/strtotime) is **not** affected by *locale* settings. However, the [`intl`](http://php.net/intl) extensions, which is typically the best resource for solving i18n problems, does have a [`IntlDateFormatter`](http://php.net/intldateformatter) class which can help you here. `IntlDateFormatter::parse()` can parse a formatted string in the given locale into a Unix timestamp and `IntlDateFormatter::format()` can do the reverse (*turn a Unix timestamp into a locale formatted date*).

```
$formatter = IntlDateFormatter::create(
    "nl_NL",
    IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM,
    IntlDateFormatter::MEDIUM
);

$timeStartDate = $formatter->parse('11 Mei 2020 00:00:00');
var_dump($timeStartDate); // gives you int(1589148000)

var_dump($timeStartDate > time()); // bool(true)
```